# Why my data is not rendering at the correct time with EJS when i access to my website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm just messing up with EJS and APIs. I'm making some GET request to an api (Pokemon API) and trying to render it to the user. My goal is to show a list of Pokemons that the API provides. I already have the data but when i try it to render it, it doesn't load at first, i have to refresh the website to get the info. On my terminal is showing the data before it renders on the website. I could figure out a way to load it first when entering to the website, i call the loadPokemon function when the server starts, but after that will not render all 10 Pokemons (that's the limit i putted on the API parameter) at the time i refresh my website, i have to double refresh to show up the next 10 pokemons.

This is all my backend code.

```
const express = require('express')
const ejs = require('ejs')
const https = require('https')
const Pokedex = require('pokedex-promise-v2')

const P = new Pokedex()
const app = express()

const pokemons = []
let nextUrl = 'api/v2/pokemon/?limit=10&offset=0'
let prevUrl = ''

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/pokedex')
})

app.get('/pokedex', (req,res) => {
    loadPokemons()
    res.render('home',{
        pokemons,
        name: 'Pokedex',
    })
})

app.post('/pokedex', (req,res) => {
    const pName = req.body.pokemon
    
    P.getPokemonByName(pName).then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        res.render('pokemon',{
            name: response.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + response.name.slice(1,response.name.lenght),
        })
    }).catch(e => console.log(e))

    // console.log(`prevUrl: ${prevUrl}\nnextUrl: ${nextUrl}`);
})

const loadPokemons =  () => {
    P.resource(nextUrl).then(resp => {
        console.log(resp);
        nextUrl = resp.next
        prevUrl = resp.previous
        //Access to the pokemon URL and Name info of the Pokemon
        resp.results.forEach(pokemon => {
            //Access to all the pokemon info via URL
            P.resource(pokemon.url)
            //Get name, type and image of the Pokemon
            .then(response => {
                //Type
                const types = []
                response.types.forEach(type => {
                    types.push(type.type.name)
                })
                //Name
                const pokeName = pokemon.name
                //Create an Pokemon object with all the neccessary info
                const poke = {
                    name: pokeName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + pokeName.slice(1,pokeName.lenght),
                    img: response.sprites.front_default,
                    type: types
                }
                //Push object into the array
                pokemons.push(poke)
            }).catch(e => console.log(e))
        });
        nextUrl = resp.next
        prevUrl = resp.previous
    })
}

//Load first 10 Pokemons at init server
loadPokemons()

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server up!'))
```

This is where i render the Pokemons.

```
<%- include("partials/header.ejs") %>
<% pokemons.forEach(pokemon => { %>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-info">
            <img class="poke-img" src="<%= pokemon.img %> " alt="">
            <div class="poke-info">
                <h1 class="poke-name"><%= pokemon.name %></h1>
                <div class="poke-type">
                    <% pokemon.type.forEach(type => { %>
                        <span><%= type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + type.slice(1,type.lenght) %> </span>
                    <% }) %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% }) %>
<%- include("partials/footer.ejs") %>
```

--- UPDATE ---

Now i've changed my code, i created this functions...

```
async function loadPokemons(url) {
    let pokemons
    try {
        const resp = await axios.get(url)
        const data = resp.data
        nextUrl = resp.data.next
        prevUrl = resp.data.previous
        console.log(data);

        //Get Pokemon's name and URL
        const pokemon = await getPokeData(data)
        pokemons = pokemon

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    } finally {
        return pokemons
    }
}

async function getPokeData(data) {
    const pokemons = []
    const pokeList = data.results

    pokeList.forEach(async function(pokemon){
        const pokeName = pokemon.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + pokemon.name.slice(1);
        const pokeUrl = pokemon.url

        const resp = await axios.get(pokeUrl)
        const pokeImg = resp.data.sprites.front_default
        const types = await getTypes(resp.data.types)

        const poke = {
            name: pokeName,
            img: pokeImg,
            type: types
        }
        pokemons.push(poke)
    });

    // for (let i = 0; i < pokeList.length; i++) {
    //     const pokeName = pokeList[i].name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + pokeList[i].name.slice(1);
    //     const pokeUrl = pokeList[i].url

    //     const resp = await axios.get(pokeUrl)
    //     const pokeImg = resp.data.sprites.front_default
    //     const types = await getTypes(resp.data.types)

    //     const poke = {
    //         name: pokeName,
    //         img: pokeImg,
    //         type: types
    //     }
    //     pokemons.push(poke)
    // }
    return pokemons
}

async function getTypes(types) {
    const typeArr = []
    types.forEach(type => {
        typeArr.push(type.type.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + type.type.name.slice(1))
    });
    return typeArr
}
```

I figured it out and now i can render the web with all the info without refreshing the page several times, but heres the thing. When using the forEach in my `getPokeData()` the web will load first before the data so it will not show the data i request form the PokeAPI. Using the normal for loop will work as i want when i make the GET request to my root route it will take a few seconds to load the page with all the info. My questions are, why is not loading correctly using the forEach? Using the normal for loop, it take those seconds because of how i made the code or because of the API response? Also is better in this case to render the web as CSR than SSR using some sort framework like React, Vuejs or Angular?

This would be all of my backend code...

```
const express = require('express')
const ejs = require('ejs')
const Pokedex = require('pokedex-promise-v2')
const axios = require('axios')

const P = new Pokedex()
const app = express()

let urlToUse = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=10o&offset=0'
let nextUrl = ''
let prevUrl = ''

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/pokedex')
})

app.get('/pokedex', (req, res) => {
    loadPokemons(urlToUse)
        .then(function (pokemons) {
            res.render('home', {
                pokemons,
                name: 'Pokedex',
            })
        })
})

app.post('/pokedex', (req, res) => {
    const back = req.body.backward
    const forw = req.body.forward
    if (back == 1) {
        urlToUse = prevUrl
    } else if (forw == 2) {
        urlToUse = nextUrl
    }
    res.redirect('/pokedex')
})

async function loadPokemons(url) {
    let pokemons
    try {
        const resp = await axios.get(url)
        const data = resp.data
        nextUrl = resp.data.next
        prevUrl = resp.data.previous
        console.log(data);

        //Get Pokemon's name and URL
        const pokemon = await getPokeData(data)
        pokemons = pokemon

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    } finally {
        return pokemons
    }
}

async function getPokeData(data) {
    const pokemons = []
    const pokeList = data.results

    pokeList.forEach(async function(pokemon){
        const pokeName = pokemon.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + pokemon.name.slice(1);
        const pokeUrl = pokemon.url

        const resp = await axios.get(pokeUrl)
        const pokeImg = resp.data.sprites.front_default
        const types = await getTypes(resp.data.types)

        const poke = {
            name: pokeName,
            img: pokeImg,
            type: types
        }
        pokemons.push(poke)
    });

    // for (let i = 0; i < pokeList.length; i++) {
    //     const pokeName = pokeList[i].name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + pokeList[i].name.slice(1);
    //     const pokeUrl = pokeList[i].url

    //     const resp = await axios.get(pokeUrl)
    //     const pokeImg = resp.data.sprites.front_default
    //     const types = await getTypes(resp.data.types)

    //     const poke = {
    //         name: pokeName,
    //         img: pokeImg,
    //         type: types
    //     }
    //     pokemons.push(poke)
    // }
    return pokemons
}

async function getTypes(types) {
    const typeArr = []
    types.forEach(type => {
        typeArr.push(type.type.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + type.type.name.slice(1))
    });
    return typeArr
}

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server up!'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `loadPokemons()` function uses a series of `.then()` callbacks to load its information. It returns before those finish; they are handled asynchronously using Promises.

You need to move your `res.render()` down into the callbacks so it's effectively serial code, or hold off on rendering until those promises resolve, e.g. by making your `app.get()` callbacks `async` and using `await` inside them or just making `loadPokemons()` async and using `.then()`, e.g.

```js
app.get('/pokedex', (req,res) => {
    loadPokemons().then(() => {
        res.render('home',{
            pokemons,
            name: 'Pokedex',
        })
    })
})
```

In either case, you'll want to make better use of your Promises and be very, very careful about your use of the `pokemons` global variable; you are already in trouble with multiple http requests trying to update that array. I would recommend using a local `pokemons` array for each request instead, and simply cache it where appropriate so you don't have to hammer the library so much.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that your are thinking in a structured way but nodejs which is javascript, is asynchronous.

Almost everything in nodejs is asynchronous. Http consumption is strictly asynchronous.

For example, if your flow is:

- console.log("starting")
- loadPokemons()
- console.log("pokemons: "+pokemons.length)
- return pokemons
- render with ejs

You result will be

- starting
- pokemons: undefined
- error in ejs
- loadPokemons() will end

To fix your code you need to use callbacks or promises. If you are new with asynchronous flows, I advice you to start with callbacks.

```
app.get("/pokedex", function (req,res){
  loadPokemons(function(foundPokemons){
    res.render('home',{
        "pokemons": foundPokemons
    })
  });
});


function loadPokemons( callbackToExecAtEnd ) {
// use axios or request. 
  performHttpRequest("http://poke.com/api/pokemons", function (pokemons){
  //at this line, pokemons was found
  return callbackToExecAtEnd( pokemons);
});

}
```

The main idea in callbacks is to pass a function to be executed at the end of another process which almost always is asynchronous. In this passed function you put your logic that expect an object with the result of previous process.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. Now I’m using axios as my HTTP request, it’s my first time using it. I read that it’s a Promise-based HTTP client but honestly I’ve never used promises before, I’m a newbie in this area. Is there a way to use Axios with callbacks or is just promises?

Comment: Axios uses promises. I advice this library: https://github.com/request/request

Comment: I could figure it out using Async/Await and changing a little bit of my code. I leaved the update on the post. I would appreciate if you could check it out. Thanks!!